# Joining together strings into Powershell variable names

Tags: powershell, nodes

I'm working with treeviews in Powershell - I have a different node for each of our buildings. In my code I'm grabbing variables, Joining them together, and using that as the variable name - but my code is seeing the variable as a string instead of the name of a node that already exists... so I'm getting

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

How can I do this? It would save me from hard-coding in every floor in every building. Here's what my code looks like:

```
$bldg = "SG1-1" //for example
function refreshPrinterList ( $bldg )
{
$bldg1 = $bldg.substring(0,3)
$floor = $bldg.substring(4,1)
$refreshNode = -join('$TreeNode_',$bldg1,'_',$floor)
$refreshNode.gettype() //Returns System.String`
if($bldg1 -eq "SG1") {
    if($floor -eq "1") {
        $count = $refreshNode.Nodes.Count
        while($refreshNode.Nodes.Count -gt 0)
        {
            $refreshNode.Nodes.RemoveAt($count)
            $count--      
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The -join operator is for strings, and dutifully gives you one back instead of a TreeNode that you want. If you are passing in a string ($bldg looks like a string from your example), then you can do all the string manipulation you want, but there is no TreeNode object in that function to assign a name to. So, we need to make a TreeNode that your function could use. What about something like this?

```
$newNodeName = -join('$TreeNode_',$bldg1,'_',$floor)
$refreshNode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode($newNodeName )
// do stuff with $refreshNode as it is a TreeNode object like you expect
```

This $refreshNode will have no Nodes inside of it since we just fabbed it up. Since it looks like you want to modify an existing TreeNode object, pass in the $refreshNode as an argument then modify its friendly description with the $newNodeName.

Comment: Ok, so now I have a node with the right name, but as you noted it's a new node and you're right - I was trying to modify an existing node. Maybe it's not such a big deal and I can just add this new node to the existing tree and replace the existing node. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: So I created the node, gave it the same name and was able to add it into my treelist, but when I do it this way it's out of order (2nd Floor, 3rd Floor, 1st Floor) because it adds the refreshed node to the bottom of the list, so I'm back to trying to just remove everything under the floor node - instead of recreating the floor node. Is there no way to take that string that I concatenated and use it to point to the name of an existing TreeNode object?

Comment: You may be able to instantiate a TreeNodeCollection into an object, then use it's Find method to locate the one you want to modify. You will want to use the New-Object cmdlet as per: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347574.aspx to create a: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed in the right direction over on the Technet Social forum

[My question on Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3af6dc1b-7a9d-45ed-9c99-fa0bdab5989e/joining-together-strings-into-powershell-variable-names?forum=ITCG)

The answer was using 'Get-Variable'
I had the two variables $bldg1 and $floor which I joined into a string:

```
$newNodeName = -join('TreeNode_',$bldg1,'_',$floor)
```

and then I passed that using 'Get-Variable' - but I had to put the variable name within parantheses, like so:

```
$refreshNode = (Get-Variable ($newNodeName)).Value
```

Now, instead of returning a string type it returns my existing string!